# How do I find out which schema script spring-boot is running?

Tags: spring-boot, hsqldb, flyway

I have an application based on spring-boot 1.4 with spring-jdbc.

I've added Flyway, which works in the application itself, but I get errors for my JdbcDAO test cases.

Question:  I know spring-boot overrides 'dataSource' to embedded HSQLDB datasource, but I have no idea where it finds the SQL scripts to populate the empty database when I run tests.

Documentation says that it looks for 'schema.sql' or 'data.sql' in classpath, but I've renamed all of the script files in both main and test resource paths, but I still get this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; 
nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Found non-empty schema(s) "PUBLIC" without schema history table! Use baseline() or set baselineOnMigrate to true to initialize the schema history table.
```

This error leads me to believe that Spring-boot had created a schema definition BEFORE Flyway scripts were applied.

UPDATE:  I'm getting a different error now, this is a Bad SQL error:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO BLUECOST_SSCDATA (SSCDATAID,PROCESSGROUPID,COSTINGAMOUNT,CHRG_TYP_CD,CONTROL_GROUP_CD,ACCOUNT_ID,CHRGHS_END_DT,ORIG_LOC_CD,SERVICE_TYP_CD,SERVICE_CD,SERVICE_GROUP_ID,SERVICE_ENV_CD,SERVICE_ADDER_CD,SERVICE_RESTYP_CD,RATECLAS_CD,PRICELST_UP_AMT,CHRGHS_USAGE_QTY,EMP_FA_CD,EMP_DIV_CD,EMP_DPT_CD,EMP_COUNTRY_CD,EMP_COMPANY_CD,EMP_NUM,EMP_INITS,EMP_LASTNAME,USER_ID,ADJUSTMENT_ID,CUST_REFERENCE_ID,ORIG_DIV_CD,ORIG_DPT_ID,ORIG_COUNTRY_CD,ORIG_COMPANY_CD,LOCAL_FIELD_1,LOCAL_FIELD_2,LOCAL_FIELD_3,LOCAL_FIELD_4,LOCAL_FIELD_5,LOCAL_FIELD_6,CREATETIME,PROCESSTIME,LAST_ALTER_TMS,TRX_TYP_CD,FILENAME) VALUES (100,null,368.60,'CTA','EMEA    ','D286148 ','2018-03-19','SLR','SLR','SLIC','BASE',null,null,null,'OGS',null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,'IBM SLIC BV',null,null,null,null,null,'653','SOFTLAYR','INVCE ID','X91927','ACCNT ID','FILENAME1.XLS',null,null,{ts '2018-04-22 01:30:21.437000'},null,{ts '2018-03-22 01:32:21.437000'},'I','FILENAME1.XLS')]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: requires either DEFAULT keyword or OVERRIDING clause
    at com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.spreadsheet.dao.UTJdbcBluecostSSCDataDAOTest.testDeleteBluecostSSCDataByLocalField2AndLocalField4(UTJdbcBluecostSSCDataDAOTest.java:265)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: requires either DEFAULT keyword or OVERRIDING clause
    at com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.spreadsheet.dao.UTJdbcBluecostSSCDataDAOTest.testDeleteBluecostSSCDataByLocalField2AndLocalField4(UTJdbcBluecostSSCDataDAOTest.java:265)
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: requires either DEFAULT keyword or OVERRIDING clause
    at com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.spreadsheet.dao.UTJdbcBluecostSSCDataDAOTest.testDeleteBluecostSSCDataByLocalField2AndLocalField4(UTJdbcBluecostSSCDataDAOTest.java:265)
```

This gives me a clue:   looks like my latest Flyway script is not applied to the schema when running the 'mvn test' goal.

How do I turn on the debugging to see what is happening with Flyway when running mvn test goal?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed - retracting this question now.

```
<logger name="org.flywaydb" level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
</logger>
```

Comment: If you find a solution to your own question, you can post the solution here, so that other people with the same problem as yours might find the answer as well.